# Incorrect key file for table 'proc'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
Incorrect key file for table 'proc'; try to repair it
```

I am amateur programmer and i don't know how to get rid on this problem. I used Xampp Version 1.7.7 PHP Version 5.3.1

Every time I click the function on each database there is a MySQL error pop-up.

> Here's the SQL statement

```
select `SPECIFIC_NAME` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES` where `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = 'hisdb_bph_mg'and ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

> Error Message:

Incorrect key file for table 'proc'; try to repair it

I hope someone will help me and thank you

Comment: It could help if you put the structure of your table here.

Comment: Type: repair table proc; (in the correct database ofcourse). Also do not call your tables anything which sounds like reserved keywords. It will be confusing later.

Comment: @meneldal The `proc` table involved here is almost certainly the `mysql.proc` table, which is used internally by MySQL for stored procedures.

Comment: thanks @duskwuff, I admit I don't know that much about mysql but it looked like a lack of precision in the question.